# Python - Changing Matplotlib Axis from Days to Years

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to use Pandas and Matplotlib in Python to plot a sum of grant money received over multiple years. Data type "Award Effective Date" is the day the grant was received. I've summed each day's amount from grants received over multiple years with the following code:

```
    #Displays daily sums of awards from FY12 to FY16
    # *Revise ledger so only FY year dates are reported, not days.

    df.groupby('Award Effective Date').award_amount.sum().plot(kind='bar',color=['orange'],\
                                                           figsize=(25,10),title="Daily Sums of Awards FY12 to FY16",\
                                                          grid=True)
```

This plots what I need, but the x-axis labels are jumbled and illegible because it reads every single day for the past several years. How can I change this to only read the year instead of each day? I also have another data type called "FY of EffDate" which records the fiscal year for the date -- if that could be put to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this? Needs to be modified for your specific case...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(0,1000)
y = [i*2 for i in x]

plt.plot(x,y)

x_ticks = [day for day in x if day%365 == 0] # Only pull out full years
x_labels = ['Year ' + str(i) for i in range(len(x_ticks))]

plt.xticks(x_ticks, x_labels)
plt.show()
```

This plots: 
[years.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsJU6.png)

Comment: After thinking about it, I actually need the axis to read from "FY of EffDate" data type. If i just try to set it as you said, it won't read in fiscal years, but calendar years instead.

Comment: Instead of the `x_ticks` I defined, you could make a short loop that finds the FY for all of your days, then runs through it looking for unique values. Each time you find a unique value add that day to your `x_ticks` and add a appropriate string to `x_labels`. If you prefer to put the label in the middle of the year: you can do `x_ticks.append(unique_day + 182)` assuming your year is roughly 2*182 days long. Just note that the `x_ticks` you feed into `plt.xticks()` has to be in days (as that is what your original data is defined as).